Is the Set of All Matrices a Valid Set in Formal Set Theory?
I've been thinking about the concept of the "set of all matrices" over a given field or ring and whether such a collection is a valid set within ZF.
It seems intuitive to think about all possible matrices, regardless of their dimensions, as a single set. A set is simply a collection of objects, and furthermore we have imposed a restriction that defines the set, so we can make assertions such as all elements have an ordered pair $(a, b)$ representing the number of rows and columns in that element.
However, I realize that this may run into problems similar to those encountered with the "set of all sets," which leads to well-known paradoxes like Russell's paradox. If we try to define the set of all matrices of all dimensions over a fixed field or ring, does this lead to an ill-defined or "too large" set within ZF? Specifically, is the unbounded nature of the matrix dimensions affecting the validity here? Would this require considering this collection as a class instead of a set?
Of course, if we restrict the set to matrices of fixed dimensions (eg. all $n \times m$ matrices for fixed $n$ and $m$) then this is a well-defined set in ZF theory. But this misses the generality I'm curious about.
My Questions:
Is the set of all matrices a valid set within ZF set theory? If not, how do the principles of set theory prevent this from being a valid set?
If the set is not valid, how might one rigorously define the collection of all matrices? Is category theory the tool for this job? Or if not, are there other frameworks/concepts that can provide a rigorous definition for such a collection, or is the notion inherently problematic?

Just consider functions from $\mathbb N^2$ to $\mathbb R$ and it can embed arbirtrarily large matrices. Then you tag them with their dimensions.

Given that you have accepted that the set of all matrices of a specific dimension $n\times m$, call it $R^{n\times m}$, is a set, we can use the axiom of replacement: $\{R^{n\times m} | m,n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ is a set of sets. We can then take the union with the union axiom, which yields the fact that the set of all matrices over $R$ is a set.
